# Left Outer Join Including Missing Rows from 2nd Table

Tags: database, sqlite, left-join

I am having some difficulty in doing a LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQLite3 and have not been able to find the resolution in StackOverflow's existing documents, but that may be just a reflection of ....

Basically, the issue is that the second table does not have some matching rows and I want the result set to contain NULL values for those rows.

1. The Table Structures:

(a) tblITEMS with columns:

```
ID (integer, primary key, not null)
    DESCR (Text); i.e., description
```

(b) tblVALUES with columns:

```
ID (integer, primary key, not null)
    ITEM_ID (integer, not null, foreign key to tblITEMS.ID)
    VAL_DT (not null); i.e., the valuation date
    VALUE (real, not null, default 0)
```

2. The Data:

(a) tblITEMS has five (5) rows.

```
__ID__|_DESCR_|
:----:|:-----:|
  1   | Item1 |
  2   | Item2 |
  3   | Item3 |
  4   | Item4 |
  5   | Item5 |
```

(b) tblVALUES has four (4) rows with
(bi) two rows have the same ITEM_ID, but different VAL_DTs
(bii) two rows have ITEM_IDs different from (bi).
(c) There are zero (0) rows that match two (2) of the tblITEM IDs.

```
__ID__|_ITEM_ID_|__VAL_DT_____|__VALUE__|
:----:|:-------:|:-----------:|:-------:|
  1   |     1   |  2000-01-01 |   10    |
  2   |     2   |  2000-01-01 |   20    |
  3   |     2   |  2010-01-01 |  200    |
  4   |     3   |  2000-01-01 |   40    |
```

3. The desired result set:

   Five (5) rows, one for each tblITEMS row, which contains NULL entries for the tblVALUES columns that do not have a matching ITEM_ID; i.e. do not exist.
4. SQL script that gives three (3) rows, each of which has the appropriate values from the tblVALUES table.

   ```
   select a.ID, a.DESCR, b.ID as VAL_ID, b.ITEM_ID, Date(b.Val_dt) as Val_dt, b.VALUE
   from 
        tblItems a
        , tblValues b
   --left outer join tblValues on a.id = b.item_id
   where
          a.id = b.item_id
          and 
          b.val_dt = (Select Max(b.val_dt) from tblValues b  where (a.id = b.ITEM_ID))

   order by a.id
   ```
5. Above SQL script with the "left outer join" line uncommented yeilds a result set with:
   (a) Twelve (12) rows.
   (b) Four (4) duplicates of each of three (3) unique rows (same as returned by 4. above). The unique rows all have appropriate values from tblVALUES.
   (c) Zero (0) rows corresponding to the tblITEMS that do not have a corresponding row in the tblVALUES table.

THE QUESTION:
How should the SQL script be modified so that the result set contains five (5) rows, one for each tblITEMS row AND contains NULL values for the tblITEM rows that do not have a corresponding row in the tblVALUES table?

Expected / desired result set:

```
__ID__|_DESCR_|_ITEM_ID_|__VAL_DT_____|__VALUE__|
:----:|:-----:|:-------:|:-----------:|:-------:|
  1   | Item1 |     1   |  2000-01-01 |   10    |
  2   | Item2 |     2   |  2010-01-01 |  200    |
  3   | Item3 |     3   |  2000-01-01 |   40    |
  4   | Item4 |  NULL   |   NULL      |  NULL   |
  5   | Item5 |  NULL   |   NULL      |  NULL   |
```

Note: NULLs may be zero or a "null date".

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because I've solved the problem.

I am somewhat embarrassed by how simple the solution was.

In any case, my fundamental problem was that I did not fully understand that the "JOIN" clauses are actually part of the main "FROM" clause, which means that the table on the right side of the join and its alias definition should only appear in the join clause.

The actual solution is:

```
Select a.ID
       , a.DESCR
       , b.ID AS VALUES_ID
       , b.ITEM_ID
       , b.VAL_DT
       , b.VALUE

FROM  tblITEMS a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN tblVALUES b ON a.ID = b.ITEM_ID
                                     AND b.val_dt = (Select Max(b.val_dt)
                                           From tblVALUES b 
                                           Where a.ID = b.ITEM_ID)

Order by
      a.ID
```

Regards,
John